# feeling sick since 2017. how to tell if this is an evil eye/ magic or mental suffering?

Tags: sihr, health, evil-eye

I've been putting this question out there for a while on this platform, but unfortunately, no one has responded.

I'm seeking suggestions from anyone. I'm uncertain about identifying whether it's the evil eye, magic, or mental struggles, but I'm sure something's off.

Since 2017, I've been feeling unwell, losing bits of myself to daily depression. I used to frequently get sick, especially with issues in my internal organs like the liver, stomach, and kidneys. Surprisingly, my test reports are consistently normal even when I don't feel well. Moreover, I've noticed a decline in my blessings.

I've observed a pattern: in 2021, my health began improving when I started waking up for Fajr. Despite my efforts to maintain balance, if I miss it, I wake up from pain in my abdomen. it seems that when I don't wake up for fajr it overpowers me. and for a few years now I feel like crying. I cry a lot without understanding why. I used to look beautiful and had long hair. now my face has turned dark, especially my eyes. Also, my hair fall has increased and I lost my long hair to it. I have also done hijama twice in 2 years which also helped a little but not entirely.

Now, my question is, why do I feel this way even when I pray and engage in my daily adhkar? I mean they do have some effect and these problems diminish a little but I want them gone once and for all. would it be considered a shirk if I seek help from someone to gain clarity on this by checking if there is some evil eye or magic on me?

Comment: To differentiate between effects of magic, or mental suffering, consulting a **knowledgeable religious scholar** can help determine if spiritual afflictions like magic are at play. Also seeking professional help from mental health experts such as psychologists or psychiatrists can aid in understanding any underlying mental health conditions contributing to the sickness.